# Plink returning unwanted characters via C#

Tags: c#, linux, plink

I am getting unwanted characters before and after my results when using Plink via C#:

Command:

```
ls -l */informatica/tgtdynamicparams*.out | grep vaulttest| grep 'Sep  1'|awk '{print $9}' | sort
```

Linux result:

```
aaco/informatica/tgtdynamicparams2269885_CHECK_REF_COMPANY.out
cdph/informatica/tgtdynamicparams2225704_CDPHDRUGRECON.out
cdph/informatica/tgtdynamicparams2225704_CDPHELIGRECON.out
merh/informatica/tgtdynamicparams3454321_OPEN_TEST.out
merh/informatica/tgtdynamicparams3454322_OPEN_TEST2.out
```

C# via Plink result:

```
[01;32mcdph/informatica/tgtdynamicparams2225704_CDPHDRUGRECON.out[0m
[01;32mcdph/informatica/tgtdynamicparams2225704_CDPHELIGRECON.out[0m
[01;32mmerh/informatica/tgtdynamicparams3454321_OPEN_TEST.out[0m
[01;32mmerh/informatica/tgtdynamicparams3454322_OPEN_TEST2.out[0m
[0m[01;32maaco/informatica/tgtdynamicparams2269885_CHECK_REF_COMPANY.out[0m
```

I've tried the following without any luck:

```
StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.ASCII
StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.DEFAULT
```

Here is the code I'm using. I have seen replies for similar problems suggesting use of ssh.net but I am not permitted to use that it has to be Plink.

```
private string GetFileNames = @"ls -l */informatica/tgtdynamicparams*.out 
                             | grep vaulttest| grep 'Sep  1'
                             | awk '{print $9}' 
                             | sort";

GetProcessesCommands = new [] {
                               @"cd /src/trs/runjobs",
                               GetFileNames
                              };
Request(ServerName, UserName, Password, GetProcessesCommands);
```

Calls this:

```
private void Request(string remoteHost, string userName, string password, IEnumerable<string> lstCommands)
{
    try
    {
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = FormInformatiKill.PropFile.Plink,
            Arguments = string.Format("-ssh {0}@{1} -pw {2}", userName, remoteHost, password),
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };

        var p = Process.Start(psi);
        _mObjLock = new object();
        _mBlnDoRead = true;

        if( p == null ) return;
        AsyncReadFeedback(p.StandardOutput); // start the async read of stdout

        var strw = p.StandardInput;

        foreach( var cmd in lstCommands )
        {
            strw.WriteLine( cmd ); // send commands 
        }
        strw.WriteLine("exit"); // send exit command at the end

        p.WaitForExit(); // block thread until remote operations are done  
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }
}

private void AsyncReadFeedback(StreamReader strr)
{
    var trdr = new Thread(ReadFeedback);
    trdr.Start(strr);
}

private void ReadFeedback(object objStreamReader)
{
    var strr = (StreamReader) objStreamReader;
    while (!strr.EndOfStream && _mBlnDoRead)
    {
        var line = strr.ReadLine();
        // lock the feedback buffer (since we don't want some messy stdout/err mix string in the end)
        lock (_mObjLock)
        {
            if( line != null ) ListOfFilesResults.Add(line.Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried `Trim()`. I even spent time just trying to remove the characters I didn't want, but there seems to be more possibilities than I can code for.

Comment: Those are ["terminal escape codes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (this has nothing to do with the encoding although it can be affected by how the program detects the console mode), used for color and such.

Comment: In this case the color generation is likely coming from the `ls` command. Use `ls --color=never -l ..`.

Comment: user2864740 ... Works perfectly. Thanks! How do I give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

While using the `--color=never` may help, the root problem is that, the way you run Plink (feeding the command using a standard input), you make it use an interactive session. Most systems nowadays are configured to use a fancy formatting for directory listing (and other stuff) for interactive sessions to be more human friendly.

While in your case, no human is involved, so you should use a non-interactive session.

There are two ways to do that:

- Either provide the command on Plink command-line (instead of feeding it using a standard input), like:

  ```
  plink.exe -ssh username@example.com -pw password "ls -l ... | grep ... | sort"
  ```

  This syntax implicitly forces a non-interactive mode.
- Or use the [`-T` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty) to explicitly force the non-interactive mode:

  ```
  plink.exe -ssh username@example.com -pw password -T
  ```

  This syntax allows you to keep feeding the command using the standard input.

Using the non-interactive session (on a properly configured system) you avoid all the troubles of the interactive sessions (not just the `--color`). So it's a way more generic solution.

---

If this does not work for you, it must be because your server is misconfigured and aliases the `ls` to use the `--color` even for non-interactive sessions.

If you cannot fix the server, I suggest you use both non-interactive session (to avoid other possible troubles) and the `--color=never` switch. Possibly better solution than using the `--color=never` is using the `unalias ls`.

Comment: I attempted to add the -T to my code to no effect. All of this is running via Plink in C#. I set the flag UseShellExecute to false. 
 
                   ` Arguments = string.Format("-ssh {0}@{1} -pw {2} -T ", userName, remoteHost, password),
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,                 
                    CreateNoWindow = true
             };`

Comment: Works for me. Though I had to replace the `.WriteLine(...)` calls with `.Write(... + "\n")` as `WriteLine` uses `\r\n`, what the non-interactive *nix session cannot deal with. If this does not work for you, it must be because your server is misconfigured and aliases the `ls` to use `--color` even for non-interactive sessions.

Comment: You are correct. I traced back my .bashrc and it uses /etc/bashrc to setup an interactive session. I removed that call from my version and the problem is gone. Unfortunately, the production version uses a user I cannot change their session variables and it includes the interactive session. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: You are welcome. I've added  this and other suggestions to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You user2864740 !
I added --color=never and those damn characters disappeared.

```
            private const string GetFileNames = "ls --color=never -l */informatica/tgtdynamicparams*.out  " +
                                        "| grep vaulttest " +
                                        "| grep 'Sep  1' " +
                                        "| awk '{print $9}' " +
                                        "| sort";
```